# if + eval and response to output

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, if-statement, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="catalog" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="catalog_ItemDataBound">
    ...
    <ItemTemplate>
    ...
    <td>
     <% 
      if (Eval("showFlag").Equals(1)) 
      { 
        Eval("pinColor").ToString().Equals("0") 
          ? Eval("placeName") : 
            Eval("path").ToString().Length.Equals(0) 
              ? string.Empty : 
                Eval("placeName"); 
      }
     %>
    </td>
    ...

    </ItemTemplate>
    ...
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Hello, I am trying to send to client side formatted table and this field should be checked before output. I can do it without if like

```
<%# 
    Eval("pinColor").ToString().Equals("0") 
      ? Eval("placeName") : 
        Eval("path").ToString().Length.Equals(0) 
          ? string.Empty : 
            Eval("placeName"); 
%>
```

and it works however I would not like to show it if there is no set flag.
Looks like I need something like Response.Write() ..
I am not sure how to fix it.
Error code I get :

CS0201 C# AND  ASP.net Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: anyone? nobody uses it?

Comment: Where are you getting the values from to be pass to Eval()? Could that be the source of this issue?